# How do I run the camel scheduled jobs with quartz

Tags: cron, job-scheduling

I'm using camel framework to declare some scheduled jobs with quartz. In there, I want to execute my class in every two seconds.

So, I have mentioned this:
 `quartz2://quartzScheduler/Processor?cron=0/2+*+*+*+*+?`

But its not executing.

Answer (score 1):

the first six fields in a [quartz cron expression](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html) are not optional, so your url should probably be:

```
quartz2://quartzScheduler/Processor?cron=0/2 * * * * *
```